# Change div data by clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want when click on stackoverflow then change data-float-toggle to hover not click.

Can we make this by something like this below code

```js
jQuery('.top-bottom').on('click', function(e) {
  'use strict';
  e.preventDefault();
  jQuery('.top-bottom').addClass('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-bottom" data-float-toggle="click">
  <a href="#">stackoverflow</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Done sorry for this

Comment: Use `$(this)` inside event handler to refer to the element on which the event has occurred. `$(this).data('float-toggle', 'New Value Here');`

Comment: @Tushar You mean like this? jQuery('.top-bottom').on('click', function(e) {
'use strict';
 e.preventDefault();
  $(this).data('float-toggle', 'hover');
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this solution. Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.top-bottom').on('click', function(e) {
'use strict';
 e.preventDefault();
     $('.top-bottom').addClass('hide');
     $(this).attr('data-float-toggle', "hover");

});
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-bottom" data-float-toggle="click">
  <a href="#">stackoverflow</a>
</div>
```

**Here's solution to your second question:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
   $(".top-bottom").click(function(){
       $("#float-button").attr('data-float-toggle', "hover");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="float-button" data-float-toggle="click"> 
    <div class="top-bottom" > 
        <a href="#">stackoverflow</a> 
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you henry so much can you tell me only how can determination class name for $this ? i found that my code will be <div id="float-button" data-float-toggle="click">
 <div class="top-bottom" >
  <a href="#">stackoverflow</a>
 </div>
</div> so what can do for this ?
really sorry

Comment: @Ahmed  $(this) is a reference to the element, class or Id that is currently being used. In this case $(this) is a reference of the class that is being clicked.

Comment: Yea i understand this but we can't change the code to make it work with the code that i sent to you on comments ? What i need when click on stackoverflow then found id float-button and change data-float-toggle to hover i hope you help me on this :)

Comment: HenryDev Sure you are right i swear i change it because i wait you write the new answer and then mark it i hope you understand me but i will mark your answer until you see you can help me or not, in this code div id="float-button" data-float-toggle="click"> <div class="top-bottom" > <a href="#">stackoverflow</a> </div> </div> i need when click on stackoverflow then found id float-button and change data-float-toggle to hover that's only,

Comment: Sorry Again @HenryDev :)

Comment: @Ahmed What you're asking has already been done by me :). Please take a look at my solution. You will see that when you click on "stackoverflow" the value of data-float-toggle ("click") will change to hover :).

Comment: Yes it's working but with old code can you write new answer with this code <div id="float-button" data-float-toggle="click"> <div class="top-bottom" > <a href="#">stackoverflow</a> </div> </div> and you will understand me :) sorry again

Comment: @Ahmed  I just posted a solution to your last question.

Comment: That what i am talking about i do like you do but i need code work when i click on .top-bottom (stackoverflow) but you make it work when i click on float-button i hope you understand me, When click on .top-bottom (stackoverflow) then change data-float-toggle not when click on float-button

Comment: Thanks for your help it's working right :) thank you